# Matrix Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a student who is asking the question: "Why do we subtract the product of the diagonals in a 2x2 matrix determinant?" I can not find an answer. I have only ever thought that it is a formula and have followed it.

Comment: Good geometric representation here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: What are you (or your student) asking? A geometric interpretation of the determinant measures, a reason why the general formula reduces to the product of the diagonals in the case $n=2$,... ?

Comment: The formula of a 2x2 matrix goes ad-bc (the product of the diagonals ad and bc). He wants to know why we use subtraction in this formula.

Comment: We use minus because that's how a $2 \times 2$ determinant is *defined*. But maybe the question is what the motivation is for defining the determinant in that way? As GFR is saying, it's not clear exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

If he asks about the minus betwen the products substracted, here is an explanation if it can help him:

Let a $2 \times 2$ square matrix: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$
Originaly, We have: $$\det(A)=\varepsilon(e)a_{ie(1)}a_{ée(2)}+\varepsilon(\tau)a_{1\tau(1)}a_{2\tau(2)} $$

Where $e$  and $\tau$  are all permuetations of the set $\{1,2\}$ : $e(1)=1,e(2)=2$ and $\tau(1)=2, \tau(2)=1$, and when $\sigma$ is a permutation,  $\varepsilon(\sigma) $ is [the parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of $\sigma$

In general for an $n\times n$ matrix the formula is :
$$\det A= \sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal S_n} \varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\sigma(i)}$$
That means that we have a sum, but since the parity can be negative we replace in the cases the $+$ symbol by the $-$ symbol.

Comment: This is the formal definition of determinant in linear algebra, and *any* teacher should know it, imo. +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (difficult) problem: We know that the price of $a$ tomatoes is $b$ euro.
Is the following true: The price of $c$ tomatoes is $d$ euro ?

According to Book 7, Proposition 19, Euclide (300 BC), the answer is:

YES iff ad-bc=0.

That is, the "rule of three" is equivalent to say that the associated determinant is zero.